# Divide a point cloud into many small surfaces in PCL

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud with PCL.

I want to split the point cloud into many small surfaces each containing, let's say, 120 points. It's not about just making chunks of points from the cloud.

I think one way to do this is to get normals and collect approximately equal normals under one set and call this a small surface.

Is there a term for this kind of operation? Is there any predefined algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the algorithm you are looking for is called "Region growing segmentation".

PCL has pretty nice documentation about how to use it and how it works here:

https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/region_growing_segmentation.html

You should just need to adjust the parameters (`setNumberOfNeighbours`, `setCurvatureThreshold`, etc.) in order to get the segmentation you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.